# hover over a non-link

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a site that needs to have a hover-over a NON-link verbiage and for the life of me, we can't find how to add this information.  2013 SharePoint w/On-Site Servers.

Comment: Did you try using JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Are you just putting this in a content editor web part?  If so, anything in a "title" attribute should show on hover.  For example:

```
<div title="This is my hover over text.">
    This is my non-link text.
</div>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/rdenver6/4g2as03b/